# The requested Resource doesn't exist when creating a lead in normal way

Tags: lightning, permission-sets, error-messages

I have a user whose profile is a marketing user. The user can create any other Lead Record types. However, problem comes when the user tries to create a specific record type. The screenshot is provided.

I already checked the Permission Set, Profile, etc. The marketing user profile is assigned to the record type. I also setup Debug Log for the user and it says there's no error whatsoever.

Does anyone know what to do? Or how to debug this? The error is so vague I don't know what else to check.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is based on Lead Assignment Rules, in case you want to bypass this you must uncheck the "Assign using active assigment rule"